# Changing VM MAC address without rebooting (Xen + Libvirt)

Tags: centos, kvm, xen, libvirt

From my understanding the libvirt "virsh" commands do not allow you to update a VM's MAC address without a VM reboot. Is there any other way of updating a VM's MAC address without a reboot? This is a problem because we need VM's to update quickly and cannot wait for a reboot.

Currently I am using Xen and Libvirt, but I am open to not using Libvirt  or switching from Xen to KVM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address is part of the virtual hardware ABI and as such cannot be changed for a running guest. If you can't shutdown the entire guest, the best way to avoid downtime is to use hotplug. ie hotplug a 2nd NIC with the new desired MAC address. Re-configure the guest OS to use this new NIC. finally hot-unplug the original NIC with the old MAC address.